# java: check boolean in for loop

Tags: java

If `work.length` is 4 ,
I have to check the `AResult` in for loop
If 4 AResult all are `true` ,set  `result.setstatus("success");`
or `result.setstatus("fail");`
What can I do ??

```
        for(int i = 0;i < work.length;i++){ 
            if(!work[i].contains("#")){                          
                CommandLineInterface CLI = new CommandLineInterface();
                String IP = null;
                boolean AResult;

                try {                       
                    AResult = CLI.Setting(work[i],"start"); //true or false                                     
                } catch (JSchException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }        
        }
        //result.setstatus("success"); //all true
        //result.setstatus("fail");
```

Comment: You are setting the value, not checking it.what 's the problem with adding an if-statement to set the status?

Comment: if the first loop is fail,and the last loop is success.the result.setstatus() would be success. But actually, the first loop is fail.

Comment: as soon as a 'false' is encountered, you don't longer need to loop over the other elements, since you have your answer, so break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, you really don't need to iterate the loop till end when a false condition is encountered in between

```
 //initially set success
 result.setstatus("success");
 for(int i = 0;i < work.length;i++){ 
if(!work[i].contains("#")){                          
    CommandLineInterface CLI = new CommandLineInterface();
    String IP = null;


    try {                       
       if(CLI.Setting(work[i],"start"))
         {
         result.setstatus("fail");
           //no need to iterate further
           break;
        }                                 
    } catch (JSchException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: And if `work` contains three elements (or five elements)?

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter. Increment it when your condition is `true`. Check the value of the `counter` after your loop. Something like

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0;i < work.length;i++){ 
    if(!work[i].contains("#")){                          
        CommandLineInterface CLI = new CommandLineInterface();
        String IP = null;
        boolean AResult;

        try {                       
            AResult = CLI.Setting(work[i],"start");
            if (AResult) {
                counter++;
            }                                     
        } catch (JSchException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }        
}
if (work.length == 4 && counter == 4) {
    result.setstatus("success");
} else {
    result.setstatus("fail");
}
```

You could optimize the above (and reduce the code size) with something like

```
int counter = 0;
if (work.length == 4) { // <-- check the length first
    for (int i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
        if (!work[i].contains("#")) {
            CommandLineInterface CLI = new CommandLineInterface();
            try {
                if (CLI.Setting(work[i], "start")) {
                    counter++; // <-- increment the counter.
                } else {
                    break; // <-- break on any fale.
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
result.setstatus(counter == 4 ? "success" : "fail"); // <-- setstatus
```

Comment: Wouldn't breaking out the loop when a false occurs be more efficiënt ? especially if work has thousands of elements and the first element is already false.

Comment: @Stultuske Only given a very strict interpretation of OP's *stated* requirements, specifically OP has stated what to do if the length is 4 and counter is 4 (or not). But nothing indicates those are the only requirements. Finally, an optimization of a break in the loop (and to check the `work.length` before begining the loop) might be in order; but it seems premature to me based on what OP asked.

Comment: In his question, he has: If 4 AResult all are true.
so, as soon as one is false: the result is false.

Comment: @Stultuske Actually, the result is fail... but I take your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code

```
    boolean statusFlag = true; 
    for(int i = 0;i < work.length;i++){ 
        if(!work[i].contains("#")){                          
            CommandLineInterface CLI = new CommandLineInterface();
            String IP = null;
            boolean AResult;
            try {                       
                AResult = CLI.Setting(work[i],"start"); //true or false 
                if(!AResult){
                    statusFlag = false; 
                }
            } catch (JSchException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }        
    }
    if(statusFlag){
        result.setstatus("success"); 

    }else{
        result.setstatus("fail"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put a break if you want to come out of the loop if you get false the first time if(!AResult){
                    statusFlag = false;                                                                break;
                }